# Why should I use a Hashing Vectorizer for text clustering?

Tags: python, text, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

I am trying to clusterize some textual data, and I am following the [scikit-learn example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/plot_document_clustering.html) for doing so.

In the example, you have the option to use a Hashing Vectorizer followed by a TF-IDF vectorizer, and this is the default pipeline:

```
# Perform an IDF normalization on the output of HashingVectorizer
hasher = HashingVectorizer(n_features=opts.n_features,
                           stop_words='english', alternate_sign=False,
                           norm=None)
vectorizer = make_pipeline(hasher, TfidfTransformer())
```

1. What does a Hashing Vectorizer exactly do? I cannot get what it exactly does neither by the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer) nor from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash)
2. What are the advantages and disadvantages on using a Hashing Vectorizer for text clustering? In the example, it is given as an option (you can also use only a TF-IDF, but the default option is to use Hashing Vectorizer+TF-IDF)

Comment: you have the solution here: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/22250/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hashing-vectorizer-and-a-tfidf-vectorizer

Comment: The sklearn guide has a more detailed explanation, you might find that clearer: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#feature-hashing